# jQuery, update field value, but allow cursor placed in the same location in the text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a plugin for jQuery, dedicated in a custom made application I create, and I have a field that I like to slugify it.

The code used for this purpose is the following:

```
$site_subdomain.on(
    'keyup.site_register',
    function(e)
    {
        var str =   $(this).val();

        str     =   str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
        str     =   str.toLowerCase();

        var from = "αάσδφγηήξκλζχώωβνμςεέρτύυϋΰιίϊΐοόπ·/_,:;";
        var to   = "aasdfgiixklzxoovnmseertiiiiiiiioop------";

        for(var i = 0, l = from.length ; i < l ; i++)
        {
            str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
        }

        str     =   str.replace(new RegExp('ψ', 'g'), 'ps');
        str     =   str.replace(new RegExp('θ', 'g'), 'th');

        str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '')   //  remove invalid chars
            .replace(/\s+/g, '-')               //  collapse whitespace and replace by -
            .replace(/-+/g, '-');               //  collapse dashes

        $(this).val(str);
    }
);
```

but lets say, I have enter by mistake this sub-domain:

```
/example-sub-doiman/
```

and I like to delete the `i` from the word `doiman` and enter another `i` after the `a` in this work in order to make this sub-domain looks like that:

```
/example-sub-domain/
```

Ok, what's wrong with that process ? Based on the code above, if I place the cursor at the right of the `i` in the word `doiman` and press the backspace button, the `i` will be removed, but the cursor will moved at the end of the sub domain.

How can I prevent that issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am placing here the solution of my problem to help other people in the feature :)

```
$site_subdomain.on(
    'keyup.site_register',
    function(e)
    {
        var current_cursor_location =   this.selectionStart;

        var str =   $(this).val();

        str     =   str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // trim
        str     =   str.toLowerCase();

        var from = "αάσδφγηήξκλζχώωβνμςεέρτύυϋΰιίϊΐοόπ·/_,:;";
        var to   = "aasdfgiixklzxoovnmseertiiiiiiiioop------";

        for(var i = 0, l = from.length ; i < l ; i++)
        {
            str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
        }

        str     =   str.replace(new RegExp('ψ', 'g'), 'ps');
        str     =   str.replace(new RegExp('θ', 'g'), 'th');

        str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '')   //  remove invalid chars
            .replace(/\s+/g, '-')               //  collapse whitespace and replace by -
            .replace(/-+/g, '-');               //  collapse dashes

        $(this).val(str);

        if(current_cursor_location > str.length)
        {
            this.setSelectionRange(str.length, str.length);
        }
        else
        {
            this.setSelectionRange(current_cursor_location, current_cursor_location);
        }
    }
);
```